# jQuery Mobile causing CSS3 animations to refire on panel show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile to create a sidebar panel:

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/panel-fixed/

I have CSS3 animations in the body of my page (`ui-content`), which fire on page load:

```
h1.page-title{
    -webkit-animation: fade-in 1s linear;
    animation: fade-in 1s linear;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

Everything works fine, with the exception that when I click the link to show the panel, the animations refire again (just one time). Can anyone think of what's causing this?

The `page-title` class is unique and not referenced by jQuery mobile in anyway. I can only think that its simulating a page refresh, but then if the link is clicked twice it doesn't refire again.

Comment: How do you bind it page? Which event are you using?

Comment: No binding, just as shown in the code (i.e. the CSS3 is entirely JS free)

Comment: Wrap content div in `<div class="ui-panel-wrapper">`. When opening panel for the first time, it wraps content div in a div with the aforementioned class. This happens only for `data-display` push and reveal, but not overlay.

Answer (score 0):

Per Omar's comments, this works well:

> Wrap content div in `<div class="ui-panel-wrapper">`. When opening panel
>   for the first time, it wraps content div in a div with the
>   aforementioned class. This happens only for `data-display` *push* and
>   *reveal*, but not *overlay*.